# Bedeutung von Makulatur

Tags: semantics

Der Begriff **Makulatur** leitet sich von lat. *macula*, "Fleck" ab und bezeichnet ursprünglich einen Fehldruck im Druckereiwesen. Verschiedene einschlägige Wörterbücher geben aber noch die weitere Bedeutung "umgangssprachlich veraltet abwertend: Unsinn reden" an (hier: Duden).

Das verwundert mich ein wenig, weil ich die weitere Bedeutung "nicht mehr gültige, veraltete Information" für den Begriff wahrgenommen habe, wie in

> "(...) ein Showdown (ist) programmiert, die Wahlversprechen beider
> Seiten sind bereits Makulatur." [1]

oder

> "(...) Wenig später brachen die Börsen ein, die einstigen
> Wachstumserwartungen gelten seither als Makulatur." [2]

In beiden Fällen waren die Informationen mindestens zur Zeit ihres Erschaffens offenbar als mindestens sinnhaftig angesehen, dann aber von den Ereignissen (Wahl, Börsencrash) überholt. **Werden sie dadurch zu Unsinn?**

[1] Der Spiegel, Stefan Simons, "Eine verstörte Nation", Nov. 2000
[2] brand eins, Patricia Döhle/Harald Willenbrock, "Wir müssen auf allen Hochzeiten tanzen", Okt. 2011 (Interview).

Comment: Ich kenne "Makulatur" auch nicht als allgemeines Synonym für Unsinn, auch nicht umgangssprachlich, sondern nur im Sinn von etwas Überholtem, Veraltetetem, ungültig Gewordenem oder bei der Produktion angefallenem Müll. Aber es ist halt schwer, nachzuweisen, dass es etwas nicht gibt. Zumal weil es einfach nahe liegt, es in bestimmten Situationen auch so zu verwenden ("Direktor Müller hatte zur Sitzung heute wieder nur Makulatur beizutragen" oder sowas).

Comment: Ich gebe zu bedenken, dass *Makulatur* auch eine Bedeutung im Malergewerbe hat, nämlich dass man dieses "Altpapier" als Untertapete unter die eigentlichen Tapete klebt. Sie wird also sofort mit der eigentlichen Tapete zugeklebt und nicht mehr weiter betrachtet.

Answer (score 3):

Ich vermute, dass eher die 2. Bedeutung gemeint ist:

> Altpapier, das aus wertlos gewordenem bedrucktem Papier (z. B. Zeitungen, alte Akten o. Ä.) besteht (duden.de)

Im übertragenen Sinne können die Wahlversprechen (in gedruckter Form) nur noch zu Altpapier werden.

---

Ich bin mir gerade nicht mehr sicher, ob ich deine Frage richtig verstanden habe.

Comment: Hm, schon klar, aber die zitierten Wachstumserwartungen sind mutmaßlicherweise nie auf Papier gedruckt worden, sondern nur mündlich formuliert worden. Nach meinem Sprachgefühl hat "Makulatur" auch diese, abstrahierte Bedeutung, nicht nur den reinen Wortsinn an sich.

Comment: @NilsMagnus Da würde ich zustimmen. Die Bedeutung von Altpapier kann natürlich metaphorisch und / oder abstrahiert eingesetzt werden.

Answer (score 3):

Der Duden verliert schon seit Jahrzehnten kontinuierlich an Qualität und hat - zumindest meiner Meinung nach - seinen Status als Standard-Nachschlagewerk der deutschen Sprache nicht nur längst offiziell verloren (in Deutschland 1996, im Zuge der Rechtschreibreform; in Österreich hatte der Duden nie einen offiziellen Status), sondern mittlerweile auch de facto.

Ich bin eher von [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/) überzeugt. Das ist ein Projekt, das mit Wikipedia verwandt ist. Die Bedeutungen, die dort beim Eintrag über [Makulatur](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Makulatur) zu finden sind, sind, in dieser Reihenfolge:

1. schadhafte Druckbogen oder unbrauchbar gewordene Druckerzeugnisse
2. Altpapier, Abfall in der Papierindustrie
3. umgangssprachlich: Unsinn

Weiter unten findet man auch einen Link zum [Wikipedia-Artikel über Makulatur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makulatur), und dort steht:

> **Makulatur als umgangssprachlicher Begriff**
> Umgangssprachlich werden auch Verträge oder Gesetze, die nicht eingehalten oder umgesetzt werden, als Makulatur bezeichnet. Ebenso umgangssprachlich kann der Begriff Schmierpapier für die Verwertung von Makulatur bezeichnet werden, indem die leeren Rückseiten einseitig bedruckter und nicht mehr benötigter Einzelblätter weiterverwendet werden. Ferner noch wird in diesem Zusammenhang oft davon geredet, dass etwas „zur Makulatur geworden ist“. Dabei wird der Begriff teilweise auch als Synonym für überholte oder gar sinnlose Dokumente verwendet.

Comment: Ich verstehe deinen Rant auf den Duden nicht ganz, auch nicht deine Präferenz für Wiktionary. "umgangssprachlich: Unsinn" kann ich z.B. bei Wiktionary nicht nachvollziehen, der Online-Duden zumindestens kennt diese Bedeutung nicht. Wiktionary "vergißt" auch die Tapetenbedeutung und kennt außer "Unsinn" (was ich für falsch halte)  nur die wörtliche Bedeutung aus dem Druckergewerbe, nicht aber die übertragene Bedeutung "veraltetes Papier/Idee"

Answer (score 2):

*Makulatur* wird nicht nur für die Papierabfälle einer Druckerei, sondern auch für Material (früher meistens Altpapier), das der Maler als Untertapete unter der eigentlichen Tapete verwendet.

In meinem Sprachgebrauch ist "Makulatur" ein direktes Synonym für "Schnee von gestern", also Dinge, die entweder nur veraltet sind (also von aktuellen Entwicklungen überholt), oder aber nicht (mehr) relevant. Ihre Sinnhaftigkeit zum Zeitpunkt, als man angefangen hat, über sie nachzudenken, wird durch "Makulatur" aber nicht in Frage gestellt.

Ich halte deswegen die zweite Bedeutung ("Unsinn") für nicht relevant - zumindestens kommt sie in meinem Sprachgebrauch nicht vor.

Answer (score 0):

Der Duden (siehe [Makulatur](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Makulatur)) stellt nicht die Behauptung auf, daß *Makulatur* die Bedeutung *Unsinn* habe. Vielmehr geht es um die Wendung *Makulatur reden*. Dieser Wendung, also der Verbindung von *Makulatur* mit *reden*, wird die Bedeutungsumschreibung *Unsinn reden* gegeben. Das heißt nicht, daß alleinstehendes *Makulatur* die Bedeutung *Unsinn* haben kann.

Mir ist die Wendung nicht bekannt, der Duden bezeichnet sie als veraltet. Bei einer kurzen Internetrecherche fand ich nur Treffer aus Wörterbüchern (z.B. zu [Berliner Wörtern und Redewendungen](https://archive.org/details/derrichtigeberli05meyeuoft/page/76/mode/1up)), in denen über die Wendung gesprochen wurde, aber keinen, bei dem die Wendung tatsächlich benutzt worden wäre.

Ganz allgemein ist es bei Wendungen so, daß die Bedeutung nicht "kompositionell" (siehe z.B. [Kompositionalitätsprinzip](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frege-Prinzip) bei Wikipedia) sein muß, sich also nicht aus der Bedeutung der Bestandteile ergeben muß.

Ähnlich ist es vielleicht bei der Wendung [*Schwein haben*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schwein): Auch hier schreibt der Duden nicht dem *Schwein* die Bedeutung *Glück* zu, sondern der Wendung die Bedeutung *Glück haben*.

Sobald die Sprecher dem Nomen die Bedeutung *Glück* zuschreiben, kann es aus der Wendung gelöst werden und auch unabhängig von ihr auftreten, also z.B.: *Schwein braucht man*, *mit ein bißchen mehr Schwein hätte es klappen können*.

Bei *Schwein* sehe ich dieses Gewinnen einer neuen übertragenen Bedeutung als Möglichkeit *ad hoc* (also jederzeit situationsgebunden möglich, aber noch nicht lexikalisiert); bei *Makulatur* nicht, da die Wendung ausgestorben scheint.